# C++ Allocate on stack without initialization

Tags: c++, class, initialization, stack, allocation

I am writing a program where speed optimization is critical. Every 1% speed increase is good.

In a function which is called a lot, I need a fixed size array of a (small) class MyClass. At the beginning, I used a std::vector. The whole thing is small (typically 256 items, the class size is 12 bytes, which means 3072 bytes if the array is 16-byte aligned)

Now it happens that:

- Using a C-style array MyClass[256], allocated on stack, improves performance. In my understanding, this is because no memory allocation/deletion is done, stack allocation is for free.
- Using a memory allocation using ::operator new, improves performance too. Because it skips class initialization, which I do not need. In addition to this, I prefer avoiding raw memory initialization whenever possible.

So it should be even faster to both allocate on stack AND skip initialization. I can rewrite the class constructor if required but I do not know how.

Thanks,

Etienne

Comment: "MyClass[256], allocated on stack" just btw, you can't decide what will be on the stack and what on the heap, the standard doesn't clarify it, since it jsut specifys about lifetime types and storage class types. So it is the free descision of the compiler ;)

Comment: Well, that's the theory. I don't know any compiler which doesn't use the heap for new and the stack for local storage variables.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the theory... But I'm distributing binaries, my compiler does allocate local variables on stack, and it makes my app goes faster so even if it's not guaranteed, I take it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need initialization? So presumably MyClass has no constructor, and no data members that need constructing? In that case the compiler will not do any initialization anyway. So just use new.

If MyClass does have a constructor then you should consider why it does when, as you say, you don't need initialization.

If MyClass does have data members that need constructing (a `std::string` say) then I'd query your assertion that you don't need initialization.

But you're right on the other point, switching from vector to an array should save you some time.

Comment: Are you sure? Basically my class contains one pointer and two integers. I was believing that the ints were always zero-initialized. The class is just this, all public and no constructor yet (it's just a struct in fact)

Comment: Actually, using new MyClass[256] goes makes the app goes 5% slower than using the ugly static_cast<MyClass*>(::operator new (sizeof(MyClass[256]))), and the only reason I can find is initialization in the first case

Comment: @galinette Are you compiling with full optimisation and release mode? Visual Studio is zero initialising everything in debug mode for example.

Comment: @galinette I would look at the generated code. I've seen compilers optimize this away, but maybe your compiler is different.

Comment: I just figured out that gcc was configured with -finit-zero in debug mode. This was the culprit. Now everything works as expected and I've gained a very significant 6% speed